# Ambiguous class name in Java

Tags: java, package

Currently I'm working with API which has **two classes with the same name** in different packages. When I want to use both in one class, I have to assign absolute package path for one of them which is in both cases too long. Is there any other way how to use both classes without using long absolute paths? For example using some kind of alias for import statement, so I could use something like this: *alias.className*.

Comment: This API sounds either really bad or really smart -- are you sure that you're supposed to be able to use both classes? It may well have been intentional. What library is it?

Comment: If you want to call `static` methods on one of the classes you can use `static import` for these methods without importing the class itself…

Comment: to `@QPaysTaxes` - I'm working with appengine calendar api (it contains calendar as service and calendar as model). In fact, I have to use one of these classes only once. I was just wondering if there is in java some elegant language specific mechanism to avoid similar situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in pure Java, no. Other languages let you do that, but with Java the only thing to do is to import one and use the fully qualified name for the other.

Comment: Note in particular that Groovy, which is essentially a dynamically-typed version of Java and uses mostly the same syntax, does support type aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't **import** two classes with the same name and use them **unqualified**, and there is no such aliasing mechanism in Java.

You'll need to refer to one of the classes by its fully qualified name and only import the other one.

In your case import class having **longer package name** and use other with fully qualified name .

Answer (score 1):

I've just came to the same problem again and realized, that this can be easily solved by wrapping class to a simple wrapper which will act like an alias.

```
public class AbstractAlias<T> {
    private final T o;
    public AbstractAlias(T o) { this.o = o; }
    public T get() { return o; }
    @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) { return o.equals(obj); }
    @Override public int hashCode() { return o.hashCode(); }
}
```

Creating concrete "alias" subclass

```
public class MyAlias extends AbstractAlias<long.class.path.ClassName> {
    public MyAlias(long.class.path.ClassName o) { super(o); }
}
```

Using `MyAlias` in generic structure e.g. `Map`

```
Map<String,MyAlias> map = new HashMap<>();
```